# Refresh UITextView's Scroll Position on iPhone

Tags: iphone, refresh, scroll, uitextview

I'd like to do some type of refresh of a UITextView to set the textview back to it's original state. I have a paragraph that gets dynamically populated depending on which TableViewCell the user clicks on. So when they scroll the text field, then go back and select another cell and return, the text changes, but the scroll position remains as the user left it. How can I return it to its default state. Thanks!

Comment: As a note, I've been trying to use 
[myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([myTextView.text length], 0)];

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default state, do you mean scrolled to the top? If so, you're on the right track. Try

```
[myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

Comment: I did try that as well, but it didn't seem to go to the real top of the text. It only get's close to the top, but doesn't look like the default. Honestly I don't really have a good understanding of the NSRange stuff.

Comment: I just tried this with an app I have, and it works for me. Can you post a screenshot of your simulator so we can see the behaviour?

Comment: Here are some screencaps: INITIAL, SCROLLED DOWN MANUALLY, & RELOADED
http://www.angelfilm.net/external/stackoverflow/mos/

Comment: Can you manually make it scroll up to the top with your finger?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint for the line of code in my answer, does it get  hit when you reload this view?

Comment: Jay's solution below worked for me, where this answer did not.

Comment: Even it's the correct answer and worked for me,  the strange is that sometimes the text some points lower than the absolute top depending on the code environment, as @angelfilm entertainment mentioned

Answer (score 8):

I've found that if I clear the UITextView first and then apply the new text, it will automatically "scroll" back to the top.

```
myTextView.text = @"";
myTextView.text = theRealTextContent;
```

Answer (score 6):

This works if you want it to scroll up to the top:

```
[theTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

The only problem is that this animates its way up. If you want it to snap to the top, use this:

```
[theTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.  I loaded text in viewDidLoad, changed the ContentInset of the UITextView and then had to use the scrollRectToVisible to get the top to align properly. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
[textview setScrollEnabled:YES];
textview.text = yourText;
[textview setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: I actually wanted to stop the textView from scrolling while updating the content, so I just did it the other way around and it works flawlessly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one of these approaches worked satisfactorily for me.

- scrollRangeToVisible produces tons of visual artifacts (lots of scrolling when switching between large strings), and in fact only works at all in a delayed call some time (I used 0.1 seconds) after the contents has been changed, not directly as Shaggy Frog's answer implies.
- setting the text to @"" before setting the new contents didn't help, even with a delay.

It seems as if once a UITextView has been typed in, it forever is in this mode where setting new contents causes annoying scrolling artifacts.  I tried setting the selectionRange to the beginning of the UITextView as well, but that didn't help.  Sending the resignFirstResponder message before setting the new contents didn't help, either.

Because of this, I decided to delete and recreate the UITextView each time I change the contents.   That's a rare enough event (based on human interaction) in my app that it's not a performance problem.  It was the only way I could find to "load new contents" into the UITextView without tons of annoying scrolling artifacts.

My experience is with OS3.2 (ipad simulator)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the desired result - forcing the UITextView to 'scroll' to the top of its content when editing ends. But to achieve it I had to BOTH disable scrolling in textViewDidEndEditing AND ALSO reset the text in the same method.

I re-enable scrolling in textViewDidBeginEditing.

```
- (void) textViewDidEndEditing: textView;
{
   [textView setScrollEnabled: NO];
   NSString* savedText = [textView text];
   [textView setText:@""];
   [textView setText: savedText];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me what to clear the text content and then set it with the desired text on the next run loop.

```
// clear the text view
self.textView.text = ""

// set the text on the next run loop
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.textView.text = someText
}
```